# Name/definition of $\int \log F(x) \cdot g(x)dx$?

Tags: entropy, definition, kullback-leibler, cross-entropy

We know that:

$$-\int \log f(x) \cdot g(x)dx,$$
where $f$ and $g$ are density functions, is known as the [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). Does 
$$-\int \log F(x) \cdot g(x)dx,$$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $f$, have a name?

Comment: Could you explain in what problem or analysis this expression arises?